# C++ program for Rabbits that die

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, fibonacci

Here is my assignment:

A pair of newly born rabbits (one male, one female) is put in a field. Rabbits are able to mate at the age of one month so that at the end of the second month each pair produces two new pairs of rabbits and then dies.

Note: In month 0, there are 0 pairs of rabbits. In month 1, there is 1 pair of rabbits.

1. Write a program – using a while loop – that takes the number of months from the user and 
   prints the number of pairs of rabbits at the end of that month.
2. In the same cpp file, write a recursive function rabbits() that takes the number of months as 
   input and returns the number of pairs of rabbits at the end of that month.
3. In the main program, call the function rabbits() with the number that the user entered. Output 
   both calculations (i.e. the one you obtained with the loop and the one that the recursive 
   function returns) and see if they are equal.

and this is what I got so far on my own. ( my program crashes though when using numbers higher than 3. essentially I want to know if I am answering the question or not.

```
#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

int rabbits(int month); //declaring function

//begin program

int main ()
{
    //defining variables
    int  month, counter = 0, rab_now = 0, rab_lastmonth = 1, rab_twomonthsago = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a month.";
    cin >> month;

    //start loop 
    while (counter <= month - 1)
    {
        rab_now = rab_lastmonth + (2*rab_twomonthsago); //doubles the birthrate of the rabbits
        rab_twomonthsago = rab_lastmonth;
        rab_lastmonth = rab_now -rab_lastmonth; //accounts for the death of parent rabbits
        counter++;
    }

    cout << "According to the while loop, there are " << rab_now << " pair(s) of rabbits at the end of month " << counter << endl;
    cout<< "According to the recursive function, there are "<< rabbits(month)<<" pair(s) of rabbits at the end of month "<<counter<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int rabbits(int month)
{
    if (month==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (month==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (month==2) // so as not to double 0 in the else below.
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return rabbits((month-2)*2); //since the population doubles every second month
    }
}
```

Comment: Reformatted for code, but can you chop the excessive inter-line whitespace, pls ?

Comment: For the crash, you should run your program in a debugger. It will tell you where the crash is, show you the function call stack, and let you examine variables. All to help you figure out where and why the crash happened.

Comment: And to give you a hint on the reason of the crash, it's a stack overflow because of infinite recursion.

Comment: Hint, use a switch case for the int `int rabbits(int month)` function. Its nicer. I guess your problems is the return value from the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this overflows the stack for month 4.  The line

```
return rabbits((month-2)*2);
```

means that calling `rabbits(4)` will result in a recursive call to `rabbits(4)`.  Each call consumes a small amount of stack and will continue until the stack eventually overflows.

Did you mean to use

```
return 2 * rabbits(month-2);
```

here instead?  That'd be more consistent with the comment at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

u mean to say

`return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);`